# Gradle error debugCompileClasspath' to contain exactly one file, however, it contains no files, when adding a new Dynamic Feature Module

Tags: android, android-module

Created a new Dynamic Feature Module: dynamic, build fails with the below exception:
Execution failed for task ':dynamic:processDebugManifest'.

> Expected configuration ':dynamic:debugCompileClasspath' to contain exactly one file, however, it contains no files.

Tried adding baseFeature true to the app gradle, and getting error:

> Could not find method baseFeature() for arguments [true] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried comparing your project structure to the google sample? https://github.com/googlesamples/android-dynamic-features

Comment: I have same issue. I use a different setup compared to google sample. I have flavors and use a com.android.feature as base feature module

Comment: I solved this, you need to have all flavors of the base module in your dynamic feature module also.

Comment: Wonderful, please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this, you need to have all flavors of the base module in your dynamic feature module also

Comment: Hello can you please elaborate this answer because I am facing the same issue

Comment: your app gradle would have productFlavors, copy them over to your dynamic feature module's gradle. The flavors could be empty in the dynamic feature module's gradle.
eg: 
 productFlavors {
        google {
        }
        beta {
        }
    }

Answer (score -2):

I had the same error message but the problem was with the common KTS script I was using across the feature modules:

This was wrong:

```
private fun Project.configureDependencies() {
    dependencies.project(":app")
}
```

This was right:

```
private fun Project.configureDependencies() = dependencies{
    add("implementation", project(":app"))
}
```

Hope this helps some poor soul